# I needed to move row from a gridview to a database table How to?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

everyone. I needed your help.  I am creating an online workshop registration system.  I have a inicale gridview that show the all the available workshop for registration during the festival time. I am using a session and check box to get the workshop that the person want into the "shopping cart" on the next page.  what I needed to do is after righting a incial order written to an order table in my SQL database. What I am having issues with is when it write the registration data that is stored in an other gridview for the shopping cart. I am writing each row as a new entry into a order detail table.  when I do this the program does something very odd.  It seem to write all the data from the a gridview that holds all the workshop information on the first page.
code for writing the shopping cart row to the order detail table:

```
 protected void btn_Submit_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    foreach (GridViewRow row in Basket.Rows)
    {                    
                Label lblCatCode = (Label)row.FindControl("lblCatCode");
                Label lblTitle = (Label)row.FindControl("lblTitle");

            SqlConnection conBasket = new SqlConnection("Data Source=JONS\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=OFFFV2;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand cmdBasket = new SqlCommand("Insert into OrderDetail(OrderID,CatalogeCode,Title)Values(@OrderID,@CatCode,@Title)", conBasket);

            cmdBasket.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderID", lblOrderNumber.Text);
            cmdBasket.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CatCode", lblCatCode.Text);
            cmdBasket.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", lblTitle.Text);

            try
            {
                conBasket.Open();
                cmdBasket.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conBasket.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lbl_Error.Text = "A database error has orrued. <br <br />" + "Message: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the code for the gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="Basket" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="WorkshopID" DataSourceID="BasketData" EnableViewState="False" ShowFooter="True" OnRowCreated="Basket_RowCreate" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" >
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remove">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="cb_BasketRemove" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cataloge Code" SortExpression="CatalogeCode">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CatalogeCode") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblCatCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CatalogeCode") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <strong>
                    Total Price:
                </strong>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price" SortExpression="Price">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Price" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <strong>
                    <asp:Literal ID="TotalPrice" runat ="server" />
                </strong>
             </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
</asp:GridView>
```

I understand that my last post was unclear and was closed. I am at a loss as why the program is doing what it is doing. I am wondering if it is in connection with the way I get the data from the first gridview to the shopping cart.
Here is the code for the session for the selected row

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void btt_Select_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selectedWorkshop = GridView1.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>().Where(row => ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("RegisteredWorkshop")).Checked).Select(row => GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString()).ToList();
    if (Session["cart"] == null)
    {
    Session["cart"] = selectedWorkshop;
    }
    else
    {
    var cart = (List<string>)Session["cart"];
        foreach (var workshop in selectedWorkshop)
            cart.Add(workshop);
        Session["cart"] = cart;
    }
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("RegisteredWorkshop");
        if (cb.Checked)
            cb.Checked = false;
    }
}
protected void btt_CheckOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["cart"] != null)
        Response.Redirect("Checkout.aspx");

}
}
```

The code for the select gridview from where the registrant select from the various workshops:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="WorkshopID" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Register">
                <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:CheckBox ID="RegisteredWorkshop" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FestivalYear" HeaderText="Festival Year" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CatalogeCode" HeaderText="Catalog Code" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="WSDescription" HeaderText="Workshop Description" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DayOffered" HeaderText="Day Offered" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Lenght" HeaderText="Workshop Lenght" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="BeginingTime" HeaderText="Start Time" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Workshop Fee" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="WorkshopID" HeaderText="Workshop Id" Visible="False" />
        </Columns>
```

Comment: Have you try to debug your program? I am still not sure what's your problem, could you explain clearly what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, it all appears is when the foreach loop, that should only be only run through the gridview with the ID Basket, is actually accessing the data source that I use to populate the Basket ID. The data source is a simple select * from workshop(the table that hold the different workshop information. At this point for testing there are only three workshop in the table.) But, when the foreach loop fires it get the catalog code and title for all three of the current workshop store in the workshop table.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but it looks like your variable naming is off (confusing basket and cart?).

You might need to do something like this:

```
protected void btn_Submit_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var Basket = (List<string>)Session["cart"];   // ADD THIS LINE

    foreach (GridViewRow row in Basket.Rows)
    {
```

Comment: the basket is the gridview ID and cart is the session name that is bring the selected workshop from the original page.

Comment: Steve, thanks for the idea but that will not work. Because the foreach loop is looking for a gridview to run through for the different labels that I want to place in the order detail list. I explained a little bit of what I think is going on Hendry comment.